# Stackexchange Blackbox is not working with Perforce

Tags: security, encryption, perforce

I want to encrypt some configuration files in my P4 repo.
Came across https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox/ for this purpose.
Navigated to the repository and tried executing the command "blackbox_initialize".
Getting below error.

```
$ blackbox_initialize
Enable blackbox for this unknown repo? (yes/no) yes
Not in a known VCS directory
```

Can someone let me know, if I can use blackbox with Perforce? If yes, could you please share the details about the same?

Comment: The documentation for `blackbox_initialize` says that it works with a git/hg repo only.  I think to use it with Perforce you need to add files manually.  I assume the model would be that you encrypt them in the workspace before submitting, and decrypt them after syncing.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for the response. I am able to encrypt and decrypt the files. But the main issue is with blackbox_addadmin. I am unable to add/remove admins.
ERROR: This must be run in a VCS repo: git, hg, or svn.
Exiting...